# blueimp jquery-file-upload: Deprecated Blobstore Files API used in write_blob()

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

It seems like the `write_blob` function ([found here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/gae-python/main.py)) uses the deprecated Files API from the Blobstore.

```
def write_blob(self, data, info):
    blob = files.blobstore.create(
        mime_type=info['type'],
        _blobinfo_uploaded_filename=info['name']
    )
    with files.open(blob, 'a') as f:
        f.write(data)
    files.finalize(blob)
    return files.blobstore.get_blob_key(blob)
```

[See here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Writing_files_to_the_Blobstore) for deprecation info

How might this function be rewritten?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Files API to the Blobstore has not just been deprecated without any alternative. [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/overview) (hereafter: GCS) is the more future-friendly way to perform such operations. You can find sample code [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted) that shows how to create files, stat files, delete files, etc. in a GCS bucket. You can read [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions) for more in-depth documentation on the GCS client library functions.

Comment: Also, [pretty much everything on this page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/) other than the files API (with the little "deprecated!" tag beside the subheading) is still viable.